# C# - creating multiple files with specific names

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've started to learn about `System.IO` in C# and I want to achieve something like this:

- I have two buttons and one `TextBox`.
- **The first button** event is supposed to use `FolderBrowserDialog` and let me choose a specific a folder.Then, to save its path in a variable.
- **The text box** is supposed to get as a value the number of folders that I want to create in the choosen path.
- **The second button** is going to create the number of folders(**with different name each**) written in the textbox at the first button specified path.

My buttons and textbox events so far:

```
...
int value;
String path;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (fbd.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(fbd.SelectedPath);
        path = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;//store selected path to variable "path"
    }
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);//store the value from the textbox in variable "value"
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))//if selected path exists
    {
        for(int i=0;i<value;i++)//trying to go through as folders as I wrote in the TextBox
        {           
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "something");//is something wrong here, I guess.
        } 
     }  
}
```

My questions so far:

- what's wrong with my code ?
- how can I create each time the `for(){}` executes a folder with different name ?

I would appreciate any help

Comment: I don't see you using the `i` variable in your loop.  I'm guessing that's the issue.  Use the `Path.Combine()` function to create the folder names.

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the `!` from your `if` statement.

Comment: to answer your second question, you can append i to the path

Comment: Try Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path,string.format("something{0}",i))

Comment: And you cant create a subdirectory if (!Directory.Exists(path)) the directory does not exist...

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger More to the point the directory exists because it was picked from a `FolderBrowserDialog`, so unless it is removed between selecting and hitting button2 the `if` will always be false.  `Directory.CreateDirectory` will create all directories in the path that do not exist.

Comment: @juharr you cant be sure though that one hit button1 before button2...

Comment: @juharr not with the code we've seen so far

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger In that case `path` would be `null` and that's really what should be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int value;
string path = null;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (fbd.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(fbd.SelectedPath);
        path = fbd.SelectedPath; //fbd not folderBrowserDialog1

    }
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);//store the value from the textbox in variable "value"
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (path != null && Directory.Exists(path))
        for(int i=0;i<value;i++)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path,string.Format("SomeFolder{0}",i)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Florian. You forgot a `)`. Even though, it tells me that `string does not contain a definition for 'format' `. Any hint ?

Comment: @Alexander big F and you are there =)

Comment: that solved it. But unfortunately, still no success. It doesn't create any folder.

Comment: @Alexander you got a wrong line using some folderbrowser dialog named folderbrowserdialog1 ... created with designer

Comment: @ Florian, still doesn't work. I can't figure it out. There's no error but the folders are not being created.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much @Florian. If it's possible, another question: how can I create specific names(for folders) using a function which creates random names ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72359/discussion-between-florian-schmidinger-and-alexander).